# String to Double Conversion (Comma to dot issue)

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, silverlight, type-conversion

Struggling with the basics - I'm trying to code a simple currency converter. The XML provided by external source uses comma as a decimal separator for exchange rate (kurs_sredni):

```
<pozycja>
    <nazwa_waluty>bat (Tajlandia)</nazwa_waluty>
    <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
    <kod_waluty>THB</kod_waluty>
    <kurs_sredni>0,1099</kurs_sredni>
</pozycja>
```

I already managed to load the data from XML into a nifty list of objects (kursyAktualne), and now i'm trying to do the math. I'm stuck with conversion.

First of all i'm assigning "kurs_sredni" to a string, trying to replace "," with "." and converting the hell out of it:

```
string kursS = kursyAktualne[iNa].kurs_sredni;
kursS.Replace(",",".");
kurs = Convert.ToDouble(kursS);
MessageBox.Show(kurs.ToString());
```

The messagebox show 1099 instead of expected 0.1099 and kursS still has comma, not dot.

Tried toying with some cultureInfo stuff i googled, but that was too random. I need to understand how to control this.

Comment: Strings in C# are immutable. Did you mean `kursS = kursS.Replace(",",".");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `Replace` method returns new string with replaced characters. It does not modify your original string.

So you need to reassign it:

```
kursS = kursS.Replace(",",".");
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `decimal.Parse` but specify a `CultureInfo`. There's nothing "random" about it - pick an appropriate `CultureInfo`, and then use that. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var french = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
        decimal value = decimal.Parse("0,1099", french);
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 0.1099
    }
}
```

This is just using French as *one* example of a culture which uses `,` as a decimal separator. It would probably make sense to use the culture of the origin of the data.

Note that `decimal` is a better pick for currency values than `double` - you're trying to represent an "artificial" construct which is naturally specified in base10, rather than a "natural" continuous value such as a weight.

(I would also be wary of a data provider who provides data in a non-standard format. If they're getting that wrong, who knows what else they'll get wrong. It's not like XML doesn't *have* a well-specified format for numbers...)

Comment: Why French? Looks more like Czech :)

Comment: @abatishchev: As I said in the answer, I just used French as an example of one culture using comma as a decimal separator.

Comment: I know, I've read your answer. Just kidding. Ok. maybe it was a silly one.

Answer (score 0):

Replace returns a string. So you need an assignment.

```
kursS = kursS.Replace(",", ".");
```

There is "neater" way of doing this by using CulturInfo. Look this up on the MSDN website.

Answer (score 0):

You replace result isn't used, but the original value that doesn't contain the replace.
You should do:

```
kursS = kursS.Replace(",", ".")
```

In addition this method isn't really safe if there are thousands-separators.
So if you are not using culture settings you should do:

```
kursS = kursS.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", ".")
```